# reuse an usercontrol(View) with different ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, caliburn.micro

I'll go directly to my issue. :)

I use Caliburn.Micro and mvvm.
16 Usercontrols are on my MainView. All are looking the same with some buttons, labels,… like that:

```
<UserControl x:Class=" Projectxy.usercontrolexample01View"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Projectxy"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="305"> 
<Grid>
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Width="75"/>
<Label x:Name="label" Content="Label"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I call the usercontrol in the MainView like:

```
<ContentControl Name=" usercontrolexample01Model" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
<ContentControl Name=" usercontrolexample02Model" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

(I don't plot the Bootstrapper because I think it's not necessary for my question...?)

What I want is not to add 16 times the same xaml code in my project like that:

```
usercontrolexample01View.xaml
usercontrolexample01ViewModel.cs

usercontrolexample02View.xaml
usercontrolexample02ViewModel.cs

…
```

It is hard to change 16 xaml files if I want to change something...

I want 16 Views in my MainView and 16 ViewModels (for every time I reuse it in the MainView) but "behind" the 16 Views should be just 1 xaml-file which should be reused(usercontrolexampleView.xaml).

```
usercontrolexampleView.xaml
usercontrolexample01ViewModel.cs
usercontrolexample02ViewModel.cs
usercontrolexample03ViewModel.cs
```

Is there any way to reuse 1 Usercontrol (xaml-file) with Caliburn.Micro? I didn’t find some articles about that... :( (There are some with the same titel but they have other focuses  like this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347693/how-to-reuse-a-wpf-view).)
Finaly I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755898/mvvm-reuse-views-with-multiple-viewmodels) which is more in my direction.... But how could I manage that with Caliburn? Maybe someone have a code snipped with explanations for me?

I hope my question is clear. I'm just new to stackoverflow, wpf and caliburn micro... And not that familiar with english... :(

Thanks for all suggestions!

Comment: Why are there multiple VMs for one UserControl (View)?

Comment: Okay there schould be one VM for one reuse of the View :). In the end every reuse of the View represents one client... thats why i want to use many VMs. hope it's clear? :)

Comment: You have the same view and different ViewModel, and the behavior of the view change based on the instantiated ViewModel class ?

Comment: If i understand your need, you must use the Factory DesignPattern in you View.cs code

Comment: @S.Gmiden Yes the behavior of the view change based on the instantiated ViewModel class. I will look after that DesignPattern thx :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Caliburn.Micro` picks views for view models based on a naming convention. If you have a view model class (it should be in a file in the `<appfolder>/ViewModels/` subfolder and named `<name>ViewModel.cs`), it will look for a view called 'View.xaml' user control in the `<appfodler>/Views/` subfolder, and if it finds it, use it for displaying the view model.

In your case, you can have as many instances of your particular view model in your main view model, and then bind them to a `ContentControl` - each will use the same, once defined view, because they are of the same type.

E.g.: Say your view model is called `SubViewModel`, and you have created a view for it, called `SubView.xaml`. In main view model, define arbitrary number of instances,

```
public SubViewModel sVM1 {get;set;}
public SubViewModel sVM2 {get;set;}
```

(or even make a `List<SubviewModel>` of them), and in the main view, place them where you like,

```
...
<ContentControl Name="sVM1"/>
....
<ContentControl Name="sVM2"/>
```

then they will all be displayed using the `SubView.xaml`. (Also note that there is another binding covention here in place: By naming the `ContentControl` the same as the `SubViewModel` instances, they are automatically bound by `caliburn.micro`).

Comment: okay if i understand your answer i have in the and 1 xaml (view) and one viewmodel. But many instances of the ViewModel. Is there at the end a problem if I use many threads to "use" this viemodel?

Comment: You don't have to use `many threads´, just several instances. That is no problem at all.